# does the following sentence mean that economic aspect of decision making is not so important?

Tags: meaning-in-context

does this sentence mean that economic aspect of decision making is not so important?

> Whether aid giving as it has been practiced to date should continue or be augmented is a vital question. The weight of evidence, however, seems not to convince, or possibly ***the economic case does not count for much in the scales of decision making.***

[Development Economics through the
 Decades : A Critical Look at 30 Years of the World
 Development Report (2008), by Shahid Yusuf,p 83.](https://openknowledge.worldbank.org/bitstream/handle/10986/2586/47108.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Answer (score 1):

The English idiom **count for** means *to have value, importance or worth*. Your dictionary's definition of **count** will include this idiom, and your dictionary should always be the first reference you consult when you have a question about usage in English.

In your sentence, subsitute *have much importance* for *count for much*. The meaning is then quite clear:

> The weight of evidence, however, seems not to convince, or possibly the economic case does not *have much importance* in the scales of decision making.